# SPList.Delete() vs. SPWeb.Lists.Delete(SPList)

Tags: development, list, delete

Assuming I already have the list object, is there some difference between calling its `Delete` extension as opposed to removing it from the `Lists` collection? Why would I ever choose the latter?

Answer (score 1):

Basically both methods do the same thing, but SPList.Delete() is a method of SPList object, where SPWeb.Lists.Delete(guid) is a method of SPListCollection object as SPWeb.Lists represents a SPListCollection object, so you can easily understand, in most of the cases you will find SPList.Delete() suitable to your need - because it is straightforward and also efficient as you dont get the collection first (negligible though), i tend to always follow the first one

It's hard to find cases where you may find SPWeb.Lists.Delete(guid) more suitable, one possible cases (highly unlikely situation) - say you have a list of list-guids which you need to delete, then rather than getting SPList reference for each and every list you can just delete the list using this method